# Hibernate missing Commit and Rollback?

Tags: java, hibernate

[I'm following this guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm) and gives me an error on `Commit and Rollback`. The only methods `tx` has is `getStatus() getTimeout() and setTimeOut()`  and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
import com.atp.servlets.GeneralSetup;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException; 

public Integer addGeneralSetup(String name) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer employeeID = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            GeneralSetup employee = new GeneralSetup();
            employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return employeeID;

    }
```

> Cannot resolve method Rollback()
>
> Cannot resolve method Commit()

Comment: Seems to me 
you are using wrong dependency, check if this is your class https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you do not have javax.persistence API library in your classpath.

`org.hibernate.Transaction` extends from `javax.persistence.EntityTransaction` interface and the `rollback` and `commit` methods are from there.

Try adding this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where is pom.xml? I dont think i have.

Comment: just download this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final and add to classpath if your not using maven

Comment: @xaa , jpa its the DANCE and Hibernate could be a DANCER !